# How to recursively keep on adding child object to parent if a child object is found on child

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a scenario where I get list of child objects in json whose keys are like

```
{
    "text": "Hellojson",
    "child": [{
        "somefirstchildkey": "somefirstchildValue",
        "child": [{
                "someSecondchildkey": "someSecondchildValue",
                "child": [{
                    "someSecondchildkey": "someSecondchildValue",
                    "child": [{

                    }]
                }]
            }

        ]
    }]
}
```

So this is like nested dynamic child . So right now, I am able to fetch parent and child but in this case there are continuous child getting added to child so in this case previous child will become parent of next child.
Code which I have implemented us:

```
for currentCategory in categories{

                    var parentCategory : rootParent?
                    //  If the object exists use it
                    if let thisCategory = self.coreData.fetchWithPredicate(CoreDataEntities.MyCategories.rawValue, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "id = %@ ,thisCategoryID)) as? [MyCategories],
                        firstObject = thisCategory.first {
                        parentCategory = firstObject
                       )
                    }
                        ///  Insert a parent category as they're all top level from the API call
                    else {
                        parentCategory = self.coreData.insertNewObject(CoreDataEntities. MyCategories.rawValue,
                            keyValues: ["id" : currentCategory.id!]) as? MyCategories
                        Log.verbose?.message("Category inserted : \(parentCategory)")
                    }


                    /// Guard against if there are child categories
                    guard let children = currentCategory.children where children.count > 0 else {
                        //  Save the context
                        self.coreData.saveStore()
                        continue
                    }

                    for thisChildCategory in children {

                        //   If the child doesn't exist, then create a new one
                        //  Guard ID
                        guard let thisChildID = thisChildCategory.id else {
                            Log.verbose?.message("Category Child insertion error : No Child ID")
                            continue
                        }

                        //  Guard exisitance
                        if let currentChild = self.coreData.fetchWithPredicate(CoreDataEntities. MyCategories.rawValue, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", thisChildID)) as? [MyCategories] where currentChild.count > 0 {
                            Log.verbose?.message("Category Child insertion not needed, already exists \(thisChildID), child \(currentChild)")
                            continue
                        }

                        //  Create new object
                        if let currentChildCategory  = self.coreData.insertNewObject(CoreDataEntities. MyCategories.rawValue,keyValues: ["id" : thisChildCategory.id!]) as? MyCategories {

                            //  Set as parent category
                            currentChildCategory.parentCategory = parentCategory


                            //  Save the context
                            self.coreData.saveStore()

                            Log.verbose?.message("Child Category Inserted \(currentChildCategory.id) with colours \(currentChildCategory.colours?.allObjects) and sizes \(currentChildCategory.sizes?.allObjects)")

                        }
                    }

                }
```

So, using this code I am only able to access first level parent and its corresponding child , inner child and parents are not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I might have made some typos and also may have got the types a bit wrong but in general this should work. The function below will get the root for a child.

```
func getRootCategoryForChildCategory(_ child:MyCategories) -> rootParent
{
    var recursiveCategory:rootParent = currentChildCategory.parentCategory

    while(true)
    {
        if (recursiveCategory.parentCategory != nil)
        {
            recursiveCategory = recursiveCategory.parentCategory
        }
        else
        {
            return recursiveCategory
        }

    }
}
```

Then do, after:

```
//  Set as parent category
currentChildCategory.parentCategory = parentCategory
```

`self.getRootCatergoryForChildCategory(currentChildCategory).children.append(currentChildCategory)`